# Php and ajax: Why is my dependable drop-down list not working?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I am trying to write two dependable drop-down list in my php, country and city, where city should be based on the value of the first drop-down list, country. While the first drop-down list is working as expected, the second one is empty. My ajax function is not working. Here are the main.php and the hscity.php, which contains the mysqli query for the second drop-down list.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="charset=utf-8" />
<title>Enter student info</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch_select(val)
{
  $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'hscity.php',
  data: {
  get_option:val
  },
  success: function (response) {
  document.getElementById("hscity").innerHTML=response; 
  }, 
  error : function ($responseObj){
         alert("Something went wrong while processing your request.\n\nError => "
             + $responseObj.responseText);
     }
  });
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<p>
<label for="hscountry">
<select name='hscountry' id = 'hscountry' onchange = 
"fetch_select(this.value);">
<option selected disabled>Please select from below</option>
<?php

    $host = 'myhost';
    $username = 'myusername';
    $password = 'mypassword';
    $database = $username.'DB';

    $dbcon = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database)
       or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    print 'Connected successfully!<br>';


    $query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT country FROM highschools";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query1)
      or die('Query failed: '. mysqli_error($dbcon));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['country'] . "'>" . $row['country'] . "</option>";
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result1);
    mysqli_close($dbcon);
?>
</select>
</label>

<select id = 'hscity'>
<option selected disabled>Please select from below</option>
</select>
```

Here is the hscity.php:

```
{
<?php
if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
{
$host = 'myhost';
$username = 'myusername';
$password = 'mypassword';
$database = $username.'DB';
$hscountry = $_POST['get_option'];



$dbcon = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database)
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    print 'Connected successfully!<br>';

$query2 = "CALL gethscities('$hscountry')";
$result2 = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query2)
    or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['city'] . "'>" . $row['city'] . "</option>";
}

mysqli_free_result($result2);
mysqli_close($dbcon);
exit; 
}
?>
```

I expected the second drop down menu to be a list based on the country selected, but the actual drop down menu is empty.

Comment: Use the Network tab of Developer Tools to see the raw response. Maybe it has the Query failed error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP script at hscity.php is failing. Create another DIV and print the contents of your response into it instead of the #hcity select to get a look at the error output, **if** your PHP is configured to print any kind of error; otherwise add the following to the beginning of hscity.php:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You can also check the Developer tools by reloading the page with the Network tab open to check the response, as a comment suggests.